# Magento 2 - PayPal Express Checkout > Difference between Payment Action

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, paypal-express

What is the difference between the following payment actions?

- Authorization
- Sale
- Order

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Authorization**   Approves the purchase, but puts a hold on the funds. The amount is not withdrawn until it is “captured” by the merchant.

**Sale**    The amount of the purchase is authorized and immediately withdrawn from the customer’s account.

**Order**   The amount of the order is neither captured nor authorized in the customer’s balance, bank account, or credit card at PayPal. The Order payment action represents an agreement between the PayPal payment system and the merchant, which enables the merchant to capture one or more amounts up to the “ordered” total from the customer’s buyer account, over a maximum of 29 days. After the funds are “ordered,” the merchant can capture them at any time during the following 29 days. Capturing of the order amount can be done only from the Magento backend, by creating one or more invoices.

Comment: There is one more option "Order" in "Payment Action". What is it?

Comment: Check my edited answer

Comment: Explanation of "Order" payment is a good one; however, can you also provide a reference for where you learned this information? Suggested reference (though for M1): http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/payment/paypal-express-checkout-intro.html#step3

Comment: What do those mean as far as magento? i.e. do any of them auto-invoice the order?

Comment: A year after my first comment (haha), here's the official M2 docs: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/payment/paypal-express-checkout.html (see Step 4: Complete the Basic Settings)

Comment: It looks like v2 API has totally redesigned, it's always about order: all chargings start from `order create`, then `approve by user through browser`, then `capture` or `authorize`. PayPal always makes things confusing while can't describe it clearly. Well there are still something about the principle `Payment` but looks like just something about `authorize` the `Order`

Comment: Is sale payment action will not work in test site ah? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/328303/magento2-is-sale-payment-action-of-paypal-payment-not-work-in-test-environment

Comment: In terms of reasons for choosing authorization or sale. Would it be fair to say that if you have stock availability issues, choosing Authorization is a 'better' option, as you would only have to cancel an order, not refund it? Any one have thoughts/knowledge around credit card fraud being more possible choosing one option over another?